# ¿como corregir, Maximum call stack size exceeded, vue-router?

Tags: vue.js

Buen día.

Tengo el siguiente error:

```
[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
vue-router.esm.js:1897 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePath (vue-router.esm.js:597)
    at normalizeLocation (vue-router.esm.js:1297)
    at Object.match (vue-router.esm.js:1341)
    at VueRouter.match (vue-router.esm.js:2461)
    at HashHistory.transitionTo (vue-router.esm.js:1865)
    at HashHistory.push (vue-router.esm.js:2267)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js:1952)
    at router.beforeEach (index.js:116)
    at iterator (vue-router.esm.js:1935)
```

Segun el error es en mi archivo de rutas, el cual lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../components/Home'
import Vehiculos from '../components/Vehiculos'
import Perfil from '../components/Perfil'
import Login from '../components/Login'
import TutorialIntroduccion from '../components/TutorialIntroduccion'
import Politicas from '../components/Politicas'
import Parqueo from '../components/Parqueo'
import Politicas from '../components/Politicas'
import Historial from '../components/Historial'
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(Router)

let tutorialVisto = localStorage.getItem("Tutorial");

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
   {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/login'

   },
   {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/tutorial'
   },
   {
    path: '/tutorial',
    name: 'tutorial',
    component: TutorialIntroduccion,
    meta: {
      tutorialVisto: tutorialVisto,
      autentificado: false
    },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      let tutorialVisto = to.matched.some(record=>record.meta.tutorialVisto);
      if (tutorialVisto)next('login');
      else next();
    }
   },
   {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
   },
   {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        autentificado: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/parqueo/:id',
      name: 'parqueo',
      component: Parqueo,
      meta: {
        autentificado: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/vehiculos',
      name: 'vehiculos',
      component: Vehiculos,
      meta: {
        autentificado: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/perfil',
      name: 'perfil',
      component: Perfil,
      meta: {
        autentificado: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/politicas',
      name: 'politicas',
      component: Politicas,
      meta: {
        autentificado: true
      },
    },
    {
        path: '/historial',
        name: 'historial',
        component: Historial,
        meta:{
          autentificado: true
        }
    }
  ]
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let usuario = firebase.auth().currentUser; //Debe ser otra Promesa si esta autenticado o no.
  let autorizacion = to.matched.some(record=>record.meta.autentificado);
  let tutorialVisto = to.matched.some(record=>record.meta.tutorialVisto);
  if (autorizacion && !usuario) {
    next('login');
  }
  else if (!autorizacion && usuario) {
    next('home');
  } 
  else{
    next();
  }   
})
export default router;
```

El problema surge cuando me encuentro en la vista `parqueo` y luego al darle en cerrar sesión, no me redirecciona a la vita `login` si no que me da ese error y se queda en la misma vista, aunque efectivamente si cierra sesión en firebase. Si me encuentro en cualquiera de las otras vistas, por ejemplo vehículos, perfil o principal y luego le doy en cerrar sesión no me genera error.

El código de cierre de sesión es el siguiente:

```
linkto(pathname) {
            this.$router.push({ path: pathname })
            if(pathname=="/login") {
                firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => this.$router.replace('login'))
            }
        },
```

Comment: Solo ocurre cuando quieres cerrar sesion en la vista "parqueo" o cuando cierras en cualquier vista?

Comment: solamente al cerrar sesión desde la vista 'parqueo'

Comment: ¿Eliminando el "if" del `beforeEach` soluciona tu problema?

Comment: ¿te refieres eliminar todo "if"?. cuando me encuentro en la vista parqueo, luego cierro session en la ruta del navegador se visualiza de esta forma:  http://127.0.0.1:8081/#/parqueo/home, lo cual es malo.

Comment: Si a todo el if, simplemente es para comprobar. Porque el error que te esta dando, es que tienes un bucle infinito por algún lugar.

Comment: parque es el unico que tiene un get en su url.. sera por ahi la cosa?

Comment: elimine todo el if y deje next('home'), en esa situación me salio el mismo error.